# Is "ASC" or "DESC" considered a "MAGIC STRING"?

Tags: java, c#, php

In our team we have been hunting down magic strings and using enums to make our code more manageable (in some other languages this would be more like constants), and have been questioning whether the strings "ASC" or "DESC" should be considered as magic strings.  Some developers think these do not qualify as magic strings while others do.

Some argue that by strictly associating a numeric value to the sort direction one avoids string formatting issues.

Others are arguing that "ASC" and "DESC" are the industry standard on how to indicate a sort direction and that adding enums for this would be over engineering.

I am curious to know what the programming community thinks about this topic.

Comment: any value "overloading" a regular value is magic. that is, are these values stored in variables which normally carry dynamic values. eg. Surname. Mr Desc will be annoyed when his name breaks your code.

Comment: If you're talking about `ASC` as a SQL keyword, then certainly don't extract it from your queries. The SQL syntax isn't going to change, and the meaning of the text is clear (the two main reasons to extract constants), and trying to string-paste queries makes them illegible.

Comment: You may want to look at this : [Sort.Direction](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.Direction.html) in Spring data core

Comment: @KisHanSarsecHaGajjar The reason for that enum is to enable type-safe annotation declarations, which doesn't apply to embedded explicit queries.

Comment: oh, regarding my comment. you are just talking about creating enums rather than leaving the value inline in code. i don't consider that a "magic" value. it can be good form to formalise that into "constants" but its not "dangerous" like a real Magic value

Comment: you could argue that loop from 1 to 12 for months of the year uses magic numbers. but unless we move to another planet, these are constants. it just depends on how much you want to abstract the code with constants considering some will never change. an indirect abstract constant definition can make the code more obscure. but on the other hand, if you need to enforce the case of a string, or something a bit more subtle like that, maybe it's a good thing. and then the set of possible constants (even if not used) becomes a form of documentation.

Comment: I was thinking that these do not qualify as Magic strings, but do not want to make a final decision by myself without input from other developers. I have been searching online and not a simple example on this one topic.  One example of this case in our code is where we are sending an ajax request and the sort direction is a separate parameter, should the input be a number or the standard token.  we are doing post sorting on data we have cached in memory and no database at this point is required.

Comment: Please don't use the 'shotgun approach' where you tag popular but non relevant tags. If you want a language-agnostic answer, use the appropriate tag. Moreover, this is too opinion-based for SO. We're not here to know 'what the programming community thinks', but to get factual answers about specific programming problems. Please keep in mind it is a Q&A website, not a forum.

Comment: Thanks Pierre-Luc Pineault for your feedback.  But as problem solvers we need to sometimes ask for input from others to 'get factual answers about specific programming problems' and there only two options for this problem either there are magical or they are not.  I am trying to eliminate the opinion factor on this by asking other developers.  But since you have not provided your answer on this problem, I am concluding that you do not a have an answer.  I have updated the tags for the languages that this topic is applicable. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks SlipperySeal I agree with you 100% making constants is a nice to formally document it, but is not dangerous in this case.  I will go with making constants.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you could argue either way in this case. I would not be opposed to seeing `ASC` or `DESC` literally in the source, nor would I be opposed to seeing them factored out into named constants. *More importantly, this decision is probably not worth the time it would take your team to debate it.*

Comment: The question _is_ tagged ruby, where replacing `"ASC"` with `:ASC` would be trivial and a no-brainer.

Comment: @Max: Unless you had `.order('c asc')`, then the change becomes not quite so trivial.

Comment: The issue is that we have code in javascript that needs to send this input to the back-end, it could c#, ruby, python, php, java, etc, should the front end send a numeric value to indicate the sort direction or the standard token "asc" or "desc".  regardless of the back-end if a numeric value is used, then middle tier will have to do the proper mapping.

Comment: @coder4life Wait, is this the same question? You're now asking about protocol/request design, while the question posted seemed to be about API design. These are very different things, and do not have the same answer.

Comment: I was mentioning one aspect of how this is applicable in our code.  But other cases are where we have if statements before we do the proper sorting, as we never trust input from the outside and check what direction needs to be used on the data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Passing in String literals to specify sort order is bad practice.

It's not an industry standard or even close to it. Consider Java's `Collections.sort`, Haskell's `sortBy`, C++ `std::sort`, ruby's `Enumerable.sort_by` or C#'s `Enumerable.OrderBy/-Descending`. None of them use `"ASC"` or `"DESC"` anywhere.

They're not even string literals in SQL, they're keywords and as such they're are strictly syntax checked.

By using a proper enum in a statically typed language, the compiler will check things like "does this function sort data or was that a data field?" "Did I get the argument order right?" "What's the string for arbitrary order"? "Was there an accidental space or transposition anywhere?"

"ASC" and "DESC" are much better than `1` and `2` in a JSON or XML request, but that's an entirely different question.

Comment: You do have a valid point in that these functions do not use "ASC" or "DESC" to indicate what order the collection needs to be sorted by.  
As one need to code Comparators in the case of Javascript, C#, Java to indicate what makes an item equal or less or greater to others and at times one need to reverse the collection. 
My comment on industry standard was about input options for example ODATA did not introduce a new sorting direction for their API, or jqGrid or while in SQL all database engines 
that I know of have accepted the that 'ASC' or 'DESC' is standard. You got me thinking now.

Comment: Sorry, not more characters left, on the previous post, it is true these are reserved keywords in SQL and one must match exactly these literals, but so can we make our code.
We will only ever have two directions, if the input does not match exactly 'ASC', then 'DESC' will be considered.
I am totally on board for other conditions where the benefit are plainly clear, but for this one I am not so sure.
I am really thankful for your feedback because because I did not even think about the separation of API Design and Request/Protocol Design until you mentioned it. Again you got me thinking now.

Comment: BTW, I do agree that "ASC" or "DESC" is more readable in for json/xml requests

Comment: @coder4life If you use `select * from foo order by bar ASC` in SQL then you should use enums, because that's the closest semantic match in Java (two distinct values verified at compile time). If you use `execute immediate concat("select * from foo order by bar ", cond(? = "ASC", "ASC", "DESC"))` in SQL then you can use Strings, because that's the closest match in Java (multiple values that fuzzily map to two distinct values at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

In a statically typed language you should absolutely go with enums instead of string constants. The reason for this is simple - lower the chance of programmer mistakes. If your method accepts a string, the user of your method can pass any string. Sure, `"Asc"` and `"Desc"` are the ones that are probably almost always going to be passed to it, but people have fat fingers and sooner or later someone is going to write `"Acs"` and the world might blow up during runtime.

Compare this to an enum. With a runtime there are only two valid values. If you pass anything else you get a compile error.

Thus by using enums instead of strings you are trading runtime errors for compile errors which is always a good idea. Using strings for any type of data that is not actually a string is generally bad domain modelling that increases the risk of errors.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have been going back and forth on this. The purist side of me is saying do enums as we are doing for all the other strings, but the pragmatic side is telling me, that it maybe overkill.  So, I am going for a compromise, we will take "ASC" and "DESC" over the wire, and in the middle tier have a helper class SortHelper with 3 static methods GetSortDirection, IsSortDirectionAsceding, and IsSortDirectionDescending.  We will hide that logic and reuse our helper everywhere we need to check or get the value, then in the helper have GetSortDirection return our enum value.